# How to hide keyboard in jQueryMobile page in a Phonegap app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with hiding keyboard in the iPhone simulator. My HTML code:

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="search" id="searchBar" />
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function() {
  one = $('#searchBar').val();
  console.log(one);
  doSearch(one);
  return false;
});
```

Everything works as I need: I can get form value and perform some Ajax. But when the function returns false, the virtual keyboard in the iPhone simulator is still visible. How to hide the keyboard? Is there another method to do that? I need to pass data to the server using Ajax when the user searches and presses 'Go' on the iPhone. The search result should be shown in the same page (already done). The user can again search in the same page.

Please help me.

Thanks,

--regeint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Hosh Sadiq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670388/hosh-sadiq) and [techfoobar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921204/techfoobar) for helping me.
Actually I did the following and it worked.
It did not effect the css above or below this element.

```
$('.clr').after('<input type="checkbox" id="focusable" style="height:0; margin-left:-200px; clear: both;" />');
$('#focusable').focus();
```

Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 32):

Instead of switching focus to another element you can simply blur your input like this:

```
$('#searchBar').blur();
```

It will hide the virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 17):

from [here](http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html)

> It's pretty self-explanatory. The 2nd line will de-focus all input fields, and it relies on jQuery. I found that calling blur() on the single focused textfield didn't always work. Either one of these lines should work independently, but both of them together cannot be stopped!

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, if you `return false;`, it will stop the default browser behaviour, which, in this case, is both submitting the form as well as closing the keyboard. The following should work:

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="search" id="searchBar" />
    <div style="height:0;width:0;">
        <input id="focusable" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(){
    one = $('#searchBar').val();
    console.log(one);
    doSearch(one);
    $('#focusable').focus();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try doing what techfoobar did but with a checkbox rather than a select as he suggested (a select will probably make a popup of an empty list). I've update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another focusable element (ex: a `<select>`) to your page (set its height to 0 so that its not visible yet focusable), and shift focus to that element before returning false.

Answer (score 1):

I used regeint solution but modified a bit it doesn't work because i told phonegap to allow showing the keyboard without user interaction in `Cordova.plist` i set `KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` to `NO`

```
function hideTheKeyBoard() {
    $($.mobile.pageContainer).after('<input type="checkbox" id="focusable" style="height:0;margin-left:-200px;" />');
    $('#focusable').focus();// maybe .blur() would work too.
    $('#focusable').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.blur()` method is probably the most effective one if you don't mind loosing the focus. But what if, e.g., you need it in order to keep a list of options open as it happens in a typeahead.

Bellow you can see the way I found to solve this problem.

```js
$('#keepMeFocused').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('type', 'text');
  $('#hideKeyboard').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#msg').show();
});
$('#hideKeyboard').click(function() {
  $('#keepMeFocused').attr('type', 'button').focus();
  $('#hideKeyboard').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
#keepMeFocused {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 24px;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

#hideKeyboard {
  height: 24px;
  background: #666;
  border: solid 1px #666;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#hideKeyboard[disabled] {
  background: #ddd;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

#keepMeFocused:not(:focus) ~ #msg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="keepMeFocused" type="text">
<button id="hideKeyboard" disabled>Hide Keyboard</button>
<p id="msg">Keep me visible while input has focus</p>
```

**UPDATE**: I fixed a little bug in the code and simplified the JS a bit