# jQuery mobile: Hide virtual keyboard after closing popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile in a project and need a popup with a textarea on it:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="none" data-theme="a" style="width: 350px; max-width:350px;" class="ui-corner-all" data-dismissible="false">
    <button id="dialogCloseButton" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Close</button>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content" style="text-align: center; margin: auto;">
        <textarea id="textArea" data-theme="b" style="resize: none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px; width: 100%; height: 150px; padding-bottom: 5px;"></textarea>
        <button data-theme="a">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm opening the popup like this:

```
$('#popupDialog').popup('open');
```

When I now enter text in the textarea and close the popup using the button, the virtual keyboard won't hide on my iPad running iOS 6.1.

I tried this [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780346/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-jquerymobile-page-in-phonegap-app), which didn't work for me.

When I blur the textarea before closing the popup, the textarea will automatically get the focus again (you can test this on my example site using the "Blur"-button).

**Edit:** removed link to example.

Comment: "I tried this hack, which didn't work for me." - which of the hacks you tried? Cause there are several given there.

Comment: All hacks involve blur() and/or adding a focussable element and giving it the focus. This does not work for me.

Comment: not all of them. You tried removing the element?

Comment: As far as I see, they just remove the "artificial" element, not the element that initially has the focus

Comment: Btw: My example works on Android 4.1

Comment: again: You tried removing the element that triggers keyboard?

Comment: No, since it was not one of the proposed solutions. Removing the textarea works of course, but this is a even worse hack than the others. I am looking for a "clean" solution. Should not be too hard to "unfocus" a text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$('#textArea').blur();
$('#popupDialog').attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty self-explanatory. The 2nd line will de-focus all input fields, and it relies on jQuery. I found that calling blur() on the single focused textfield didn't always work. Either one of these lines should work independently, but both of them together cannot be stopped!

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```