# Phonegap - iOS keyboard is not hiding on outside tap of input field

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, keyboard

On input text focus, keyboard appears as expected. But when I click outside of the input text, keyboard does not hide. I am using java script and jQuery. With jQueryMobile JS and CSS - page behaves correctly. But for this project we are not using jQueryMobile.

This problem is only with iOS simulator/device. With Android, it's working perfectly fine.

I even tried using `document.activeElement.blur();` on outer element click/tap. But then I am unable to focus to input text, because that input text is inside that outer element.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780346/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-jquerymobile-page-in-phonegap-app)  post may be usefull

Comment: @jeekonline I've already tried blurring an element as mentioned in the question. I don't want field to blur on some button click, but I want this on whole body click. Now If I write the script that on body click blur a field, Field never gets focus as field is also a part of body. Hope I am clear with my question now...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having this exact problem.  I focus on a number input, click a number on the keyboard and then try to click somewhere else in the app, like an empty space, and the keyboard does not hide.  Also, the enter button does nothing.  I can click the next button, but that just focuses the next input and so I can never click off.  If I click the submit button, it will submit but I shouldn't have to do that because I might need to edit more inputs.  Also, if I call the blur() event manually, it successfully hides the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

This works for my iOS 7 phonegap app.