# jQuery: Event to hide keyboard on mobile devices on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

If user focuses input field in website using mobile device - keyboard appears.

But if user push back button - browser returns user to previous page.

Is there some way to hide keyboard on back button without navigating to previous page like in mobile app?

**EDIT**

There is the way to hide keyboard $('input').blur();

But is there some back button events?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with only js. Maybe with some webapp like ionic.

Comment: have you tried something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780346/how-to-hide-keyboard-in-jquerymobile-page-in-a-phonegap-app

Comment: sure, use the history api and inject an extra partial page fragment before entering the input

Comment: @depperm I edited my question

Comment: @dandavis Thx! But where can i read more about it?)

Comment: perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24035537/3756369